# Defining sagemaker pipeline resource in Terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

I'm rewriting a CloudFormation template into terraform and there is a CF resource I don't know the equivalent in TF.

The CF resource is **AWS::SageMaker::Pipeline**

Below is the fragment of the template.yaml

```
  pipeline:
    Type: AWS::SageMaker::Pipeline
    Properties:
      PipelineName: !Ref pPipelineName
      PipelineDisplayName: !Ref pPipelineName
      PipelineDescription: !Ref pPipelineDescription
      PipelineDefinition:
          PipelineDefinitionBody: !Sub "{\"Version\":\"2020-12-01\",........}}]}"
      RoleArn: !Ref pPipelineRoleArn
      Tags:
            - Key: project
              Value: !Ref pProjectName
```

Have someone defined this resource in Terraform?

Answer (score 3):

It has not been officially added to the Terraform `aws` provider. However, recently a provider that helps people test different new features has been added to Terraform, and it is called AWS Cloud Control provider, `awscc`. An example on how to use this provider is given in [1]. There are also tutorials on HashiCorp Learn [2]. The resource you are looking for is given in [3].

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/awscc

[2] https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-cloud-control

[3] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/awscc/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_pipeline

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn´t know that provider!

Comment: @SolMalisani If this works, acceptance and/or upvote would be appreciated. :)